# Two EmailMessage same email. Why?

Tags: apex, email, emailmessage, email-tracking

I send an email from apex from opportunity object to account.

```
 Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();             
 mail.setSenderDisplayName('Test');
 mail.setHtmlBody(htmlbody);
 mail.setPlainTextBody(body);
 mail.setSubject(subject);
 mail.setTargetObjectId(c.Id);               
 Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
```

c.id is the contact id. It will automatically create a record emailmessage. 
But if I wanted to hook the email to the opportunity activity from which I send the email I get two email messages record (one for opportunity Not tracked and tow on account (one tracked and one else not tracked). Why?

```
EmailMessage emailMessage = new EmailMessage();
emailMessage.status = '3'; 
emailMessage.relatedToId = o.Id;      
emailMessage.fromName = 'PrestiYou'; 
emailMessage.subject = subject; 
emailMessage.htmlBody = htmlBody;    
emailMessage.toAddress = o.Email__c ; 

String[] toIds = new String[]{c.Id}; 
emailMessage.toIds = toIds;
insert emailMessage;
```

The logic of sending mail is invoked by an opportunity trigger. I need to "track" the e-mail sent in order to monitor it. I need to find an emailMessage record on opportunity activity and on account activity tracked both. How ?

Comment: Can you add some of the trigger code? This could be a trigger-recursion issue

Comment: even if I execute the code from execute anonymous I have the same problem

Comment: If it’s a trigger problem, you would. But we have not seen your code.